# Charts with empty months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, charts

I have a hash

```
{"Apr 2016"=>6.0, "Aug 2016"=>7.5, "Jan 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "Apr 2017"=>7.333333333333333, "May 2017"=>7.571428571428571, "Jun 2017"=>6.75, "Jul 2017"=>6.7272727272727275}
```

I want display a chart line but the empty months in my hash create ugly chart,
I would know how get empty months and give previous value has value to get something like

```
{"Apr 2016"=>6.0, "May 2016"=>6, "June 2016"=>6, "July 2016"=>6 "Aug 2016"=>7.5, "Jan 2017"=>8.666666666666666...}
```

UPDATE: I get all values but i dont know how atribute the previous value when the value is empty, i tried many things but nothing work

Comment: Where is the hash coming from? Is it possible to change how it is generated?

Comment: i edited my question to explain every steps @spickermann

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def fill_in(h)
  month, date_last = h.keys.map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%b %Y') }.minmax
  h_out = {}
  last = nil
  loop do
    str = month.strftime('%b %Y')
    h_out[str] = h.fetch(str, last)
    last = h_out[str]
    return h_out if month == date_last
    month = month >> 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
h = { "May 2016"=>6.0, "Aug 2016"=>7.5, "Jan 2017"=>8.6, "Nov 2016"=>7.3 }
fill_in(h)
  #=> {"May 2016"=>6.0, "Jun 2016"=>6.0, "Jul 2016"=>6.0,
  #    "Aug 2016"=>7.5, "Sep 2016"=>7.5, "Oct 2016"=>7.5,
  #    "Nov 2016"=>7.3, "Dec 2016"=>7.3, "Jan 2017"=>8.6}
```

**Explanation**

See [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime), [Date#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E), [Enumerable#minmax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) and [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Let's go though the steps for `h` given in the example.

```
month, date_last = h.keys.map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%b %Y') }.minmax
  #=> [#<Date: 2016-05-01 ((2457510j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2017-01-01 ((2457755j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
month
  #=> #<Date: 2016-05-01 ((2457510j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date_last
  #=> #<Date: 2017-01-01 ((2457755j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
h_out = {}
last = nil
```

Perform the loop calculation once

```
str = month.strftime('%b %Y')
  #=> #<Date: 2016-05-01 ((2457510j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>.strftime('%b %Y')
  #=> "May 2016"
h_out[str] = h.fetch("May 2016", nil)
  #=> h.fetch(str, last)
  #=> 6.0
last = h_out[str]
  #=> 6.0
return h_out if month == date_last
  # <do not return>
month = month >> 1
  #=> #<Date: 2016-06-01 ((2457541j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Now proceed through the loop once more.

```
str = month.strftime('%b %Y')
  #=> "Jun 2016"
h_out[str] = h.fetch(str, last)
  #=> 6.0
```

This time `fetch` uses its default (`last #=> 6.0`) because `h` has no key `"Jun 2016"`.

```
last = h_out[str]
  #=> 6.0
return h_out if month == date_last
  # <do not return>
month = month >> 1
  #=> #<Date: 2016-07-01 ((2457571j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Thanks to take time to explain me everything about your calculation, its help me i will try to do it with weeks and years now :)

Comment: I try to use it in week/year format but when i change strftime to (%W, %Y) i get a error

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "week/year" format. You may want to post a separate question.

Comment: I mean, thanks to your method i have hash in month-year=>value and now i try to do the same with week-year=>value with the number of week and the year

Comment: How do you wish to represent each week? For example `1`, `2`, `3`, the date of the Sunday beginning each week (e.g.`'8/21/2016'\) or something else? Are the keys in the given date range still month/year? If yes, the beginning and end of the range will likely fall mid-week. Are those weeks to be included? You really need to post a separate question.

Comment: Yes i want reprent each week with 1, 2, 3 and the keys and value from a different hash, its like my months hash but with the number of the week and year, thanks for your help i will post a seperate question

Comment: You will need to specify: 1) the first day of the week (Sunday?); 2) whether it is the first or last day of a week that spans years that determines the year in which the week falls.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Update as well.

You will need to fill the gaps:

```
require 'date'
data = {'Apr 2016' => 6.0, 'Aug 2016' => 7.5, 'Jan 2017' => 8.666666666666666, 'Apr 2017' => 7.333333333333333, 'May 2017' => 7.571428571428571, 'Jun 2017' => 6.75, 'Jul 2017' => 6.7272727272727275}
range = Date.parse('1.4.2016')..Date.parse('1.7.2017')

range.each do |date|
  key = date.strftime('%b %Y')
  data[key] ||= 0
end
```

This creates a date range with start and end date and then iterates it. It creates a String from the date (`strftime`) and checks if it is already in the hash (`||=`) and if not, assigns it with value set to `0`
Depending on how you render the chart and what you actually want to display, `0` might be the wrong value, perhaps you'll need to set it to `nil`.

UPDATE:
I just realized that this is not the most efficient way to do this because the range will contain a entry per day, not per month. I'll leave the code in the answer but you should use something like:

```
require 'date'
data = {'Apr 2016' => 6.0, 'Aug 2016' => 7.5, 'Jan 2017' => 8.666666666666666, 'Apr 2017' => 7.333333333333333, 'May 2017' => 7.571428571428571, 'Jun 2017' => 6.75, 'Jul 2017' => 6.7272727272727275}

current = Date.parse('1.4.2016')
stop = Date.parse('1.7.2017')

while current <= stop do
  key = current.strftime('%b %Y')
  data[key] ||= 0
  current = current >> 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works i need to take the previous value and not 0 now

Comment: Thanks for the update i will try it, do you know how tzke the previous data[key] and not 0 ?