# Complete hash key with empty dates

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with weeks as keys:

```
{"16 2016"=>6.0, "31 2016"=>7.5, "04 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "14 2017"=>7.5, "15 2017"=>8.4, "17 2017"=>7.333333333333333, "20 2017"=>7.571428571428571, "25 2017"=>6.75, "29 2017"=>6.8, "30 2017"=>6.7272727272727275}
```

I want to display a chart line, but the empty months in my hash. I know how to get empty weeks and give the previous value that has the value to get that.

```
{"16 2016"=>6.0, "17 2016"=>6.0, "31"=>7.5}
```

I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520203/charts-with-empty-months/45524784?noredirect=1#comment78068304_45524784) to do it with my month hashes.

When I change `strptime` to parse in `"%W, %Y"`, the view never stops loading.

Comment: Can you show what you did?
Also: what is the date range? How many days are in between. And do you use Date or Time?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked the same for months, here is a flexible approach. You might want to put this into a class and split the method into parts. Also you probably want to add :year option, if I got you right:

```
require 'date'

def fill_gaps(input, step)
  format = case step
  when :month then '%b %Y'
  when :week then '%W %Y'
  end
  current, *rest, stop = input.keys.map do |string|
    Date.strptime(string, format)
  end.sort

  {}.tap do |output|
    previous_value = nil
    while current <= stop
      key = current.strftime(format)
      output[key] = input.fetch(key, previous_value)

      current = case step
      when :month then current >> 1
      when :week then current + 7
      end
      previous_value = output[key]
    end

  end
end

h = {"Apr 2016"=>6.0, "Aug 2016"=>7.5, "Jan 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "Apr 2017"=>7.333333333333333, "May 2017"=>7.571428571428571, "Jun 2017"=>6.75, "Jul 2017"=>6.7272727272727275}
p h
p fill_gaps(h, :month)

h = {"16 2016"=>6.0, "31 2016"=>7.5, "04 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "14 2017"=>7.5, "15 2017"=>8.4, "17 2017"=>7.333333333333333, "20 2017"=>7.571428571428571, "25 2017"=>6.75, "29 2017"=>6.8, "30 2017"=>6.7272727272727275}
p h
p fill_gaps(h, :week)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to fill in all missing weeks with previous week values:

```
def all_weeks(input)
  dates = input.keys.map { |d| Date.commercial(*d.split.map(&:to_i).reverse) }
  range = (dates.min..dates.max).to_a.map { |d| d.strftime("%W %Y") }.uniq

  current_value = 0

  range.each_with_object({}) do |date, result|
    result[date] = current_value = input[date] || current_value
  end
end
```

Notice the use of `Date`, but since you are using rails, there is no need to `require` it.

To use it:

```
weeks = {"16 2016"=>6.0, "31 2016"=>7.5, "04 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "14 2017"=>7.5, "15 2017"=>8.4, "17 2017"=>7.333333333333333, "20 2017"=>7.571428571428571, "25 2017"=>6.75, "29 2017"=>6.8, "30 2017"=>6.7272727272727275}
all_weeks(weeks)
```

Comment: Just a note that this identifies the first week of each month as week `0`, rather than week `1` (which is fine).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `%U` and `%W` `Date#strptime` directives until I saw your answer, so used the former to simplify part of my answer. Nor was I aware of `Date::commercial`. All good stuff.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wasn't aware neither of `Date::commercial` until i browsed the docs while crafting this answer. It seems impossible to keep track of every method in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

def fill_in(h)
  fwy, lwy = h.keys.minmax_by { |str| str.split.map(&:to_i).reverse }
  last_val = nil 
  (week_yr_str_to_date(fwy)..week_yr_str_to_date(lwy)).step(7).
    each_with_object({}) do |d,g| 
      wystr = date_to_week_yr_str(d)
      g[wystr] = h.fetch(wystr, last_val)
      last_val = g[wystr]
  end
end

def week_yr_str_to_date(wystr)
  Date.strptime(wystr, '%U %Y')
end

def date_to_week_yr_str(d)
  "#{1+((d-date_1st_Sunday(d.year)).to_i)/7} #{d.year}"
end

def date_1st_Sunday(y)
  start_date = Date.new(y)
  start_date += (7 - start_date.wday)%7
end

h = { "49 2016"=>649, "51 2016"=>651, "2 2017"=>701, "4 2017"=>703 }

fill_in(h)
  #=> {"49 2016"=>649, "50 2016"=>649, "51 2016"=>651, "52 2016"=>651,
  #    "1 2017"=>651, "2 2017"=>701, "3 2017"=>701, "4 2017"=>703}
```